# How to fix my loop code in JAVA?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make it such that if the person typed anything else besides "BMW" or "AUDI" that they would get sent back to the point where they get to retype, I'm a beginner coder so please explain if possible :3 thanks a lot! Sorry if my code is messy still new to this and working on it!

edit: Thanks alot guys/girls for helping :3

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyClass {

public static void main(String[ ] args) {
  Vehicle V1 = new Vehicle();
  Vehicle V2 = new Vehicle();


  //Vehicle 1 (BMW)
  V1.setColour("Blue");
  V1.setFuel(56);
  V1.setWheels(3);
  V1.setMaxSpeed(150);
  //Vehicle 2 (AUDI)
  V2.setColour("Red");
  V2.setFuel(59);
  //Wheels and Max speed are on default...


      System.out.println("Choose from Audi or BMW");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String q = input.next();
      while(q.equalsIgnoreCase("BMW") || q.equalsIgnoreCase("AUDI")){

      if (q.equalsIgnoreCase("BMW")){ // Prints BMW Car Specifications
          System.out.println("Here is the latest BMW Car specifications:");
          System.out.println("Colour: " + V1.getColour());
          System.out.println("Fuel Capacity: " + V1.getFuel() + " Liters");
          System.out.println("Wheel count: " + V1.getWheels());
          System.out.println("Maximum Speed: " + V1.getMaxSpeed() + " KM/H");
          break;
      }else if(q.equalsIgnoreCase("AUDI")){ //Prints AUDI Car Specifications
          System.out.println("Here is the latest AUDI Car specifications:");
          System.out.println("Colour: " + V2.getColour());
          System.out.println("Fuel Capacity: " + V2.getFuel() + " Liters");
          System.out.println("Wheel count: " + V2.getWheels());
          System.out.println("Maximum Speed: " + V2.getMaxSpeed() + " KM/H");
          break;
      }else{
          System.out.println("Sorry that is not a car manufacturer listed      (AUDI/BMW)");
      }
  }   
}
}
```

Comment: You never assign a new string to `q` so how do you expect your loop to work? also `break` just exits the loop anyway

Comment: You're not getting any input from within the loop. How will the variables ever change within the loop? How will it end?

Comment: Woah guys go easy on me xD, thanks tho, can you give me some pointers on how to fix/make the code better, like edit it? cuz i getcha but i dont getcha P.S didn't mention that theres another class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to exclude your if and else if statement out of the loop then reprompt
the user if it is not BMW or AUDI then outside the loop test the String

```
int car=0;
    while(car==0)
    {
        if(q.equalsIgnoreCase("BMW")||q.equalsIgnoreCase("AUDI"))
            car++;
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that is not a car manufacturer listed           (AUDI/BMW)");
            System.out.println("Choose from Audi or BMW");
            q = input.next();
        }

    }
if (q.equalsIgnoreCase("BMW")){ // Prints BMW Car Specifications
      System.out.println("Here is the latest BMW Car specifications:");
      System.out.println("Colour: " + V1.getColour());
      System.out.println("Fuel Capacity: " + V1.getFuel() + " Liters");
      System.out.println("Wheel count: " + V1.getWheels());
      System.out.println("Maximum Speed: " + V1.getMaxSpeed() + " KM/H");

  }else if(q.equalsIgnoreCase("AUDI")){ //Prints AUDI Car Specifications
      System.out.println("Here is the latest AUDI Car specifications:");
      System.out.println("Colour: " + V2.getColour());
      System.out.println("Fuel Capacity: " + V2.getFuel() + " Liters");
      System.out.println("Wheel count: " + V2.getWheels());
      System.out.println("Maximum Speed: " + V2.getMaxSpeed() + " KM/H");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the user until he enters one of the correct words. So you have to do it like this:

```
 String q = input.next();
 while(!q.equalsIgnoreCase("BMW") && !q.equalsIgnoreCase("AUDI")){
    q = input.next();
 }
```

After that you can print out the information about the AUDI or BMW depending on what the user input was.

Comment: You need `q isn't BMW AND q isn't AUDI`, not `OR`. As it is, no input can get past that loop. For example, if the input is `"BMW"`, it doesn't equal `"AUDI"`, so the second part of the loop condition is `true`, and the whole loop condition is `true`, so the loop continues.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex a String value cannot contain two values e.g. BMW and AUDI at the same time what do you mean by &&? you mean it must contain BMW and AUDI?

Comment: No, I mean it should be neither for the `while` loop to continue. When it's neither, you have `!BMW && !AUDI`. See the example at https://ideone.com/SNI83R, where using `||` leads to an infinite loop (the second loop never completes).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex here I had edited my answer see my proper answer I added the logic